# Creating a JSON object with name of the JSON file and its content in bash

Tags: bash, find, echo, jq, cat

I have a few `.json` files in my directory. If I do:

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec echo "{\"filename\": \"{}\", \"content\": `cat {}` }," \;
```

I get:

```
{"filename": "./a.json", "content":  },
{"filename": "./b.json", "content":  },
```

However, if I do:

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec echo "{\"filename\": \"{}\", \"content\": cat {} }," \;
```

I get:

```
{"filename": "./a.json", "content": cat ./a.json },
{"filename": "./b.json", "content": cat ./b.json },
```

so how do I make the `a.json` and `b.json` contents be `cat`ed correctly ?

BTW, if I do:

```
find . -name '*.json' -exec cat {} \;
```

the json files are correctly printed in the console, so I know that the file contents are valid.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings. Use the the `jq` utility.

Comment: I will be happy to accept an answer with `jq` too for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Inian It will be in multiple sub-directories and the filenames will also contain spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ cat a.json
{ "a":123 }
$ cat b.json
{ "b":234 }
$ cat "foo/bar/base/c c.json"
{ "c": 456 }
$ shopt -s globstar # enable recursion with '**'
$ for i in **/*.json; do
    cat<<EOF
    { "filename": "$i", "content": $(cat "$i") }
EOF
done | tee file.json
$ cat file.json
{ "filename": "a.json", "content": {"a":123} }
{ "filename": "b.json", "content": {"b":234} }
{ "filename": "foo/bar/base/c c.json", "content": { "c": 456 } }
```

Comment: This does not work if the filenames contain spaces. This is what I first started with. Only when that failed, I went to the `find` based approach. Also, I have files in sub-directories too.

Comment: in this way you "lose" `find`. I think it would be better if the `for` iterates over `find`'s output lines

Comment: Added file with space in filename, no worries with proper quoting

Comment: And no need 'find' here using bash recursion

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer. Just for completion, Can you please add a `,` in the end of each row ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot with `find` you can easily personalize the search and I thought this was important to OP since question is asking "find exec output..." and has the `find` tag.

Comment: @peak: do you have any example to be tested ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot - Just look at the JSON spec for strings (json.org).  E.g. filenames with literal tabs or double-quotation marks.

Comment: Very specific cases.

Answer (score 7):

Using `bash` without `find` you can do below. You can use `nullglob` and `globstar` for recursive JSON file name traversal

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
```

By default `jq` provides a function `input_filename` which prints the filename being processed currently. The documentation says, it should work fine as long as the locale is `UTF-8`

```
jq '{ filename: input_filename, content: . }' **/*.json
```

To have a comma between the object entries, use the `-n` flag with `inputs` and put the entire result in an array `[..]`

```
jq -n '[inputs | { filename: input_filename, content: . }]' **/*.json
```

For compact output on the same line, use the `-c` flag as `jq -c '..'`

Comment: `-n use 'null' as the single input value;` could you explain briefly how `-n` flag works in the context of the last command ?

Comment: @Philippe: The `-n` construct is often used to construct JSON object from scratch.In the example above `filename` and `content` are created newly. When constructing JSON newly, `inputs` provides the contents of all the files cat'ed together. Since we are not using slurp mode, the filter is applied on each object and the `input_filename` gets the name of the file currently processed (internally)